# How to compare two tables mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables :

Table 1 is called "card" . The fields that are important are:

```
"state_id" - This table has 3 values (1,2,3)
"associated_driver" - called "referred_as" on driver table
"referred_as" - called "associated_card" on driver table
```

Table 2 is called "driver". The fields that are important are:

```
"ID" - The auto incremented value of the table
"associated_card" - Has a value , normally some number e.g 123555
"referred_as" - The name of the driver () called "associated_driver" on card table
```

Forgot to add this table :

Table 3is called "card_driver". The fields that are important are:

```
"driver_id" - The id from the driver table that links to the card
"card_id" - The id from the card table that links to the driver
```

What i want to happen :

When a user enters their id from the driver table, it will compare a field that both tables have i.e the 'associated card' field. From there the original query from (bellow) will take over, although that needs to be modified as well.

I don't really know how to do sql queries .

I need to change this part :

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM card WHERE id = '$id'" ;
```

Thanks

Original Code :

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

$sql ="SELECT * FROM card WHERE id = '$id'" ;
mysql_select_db('damp');
$result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
switch($row['state_id'])
{
case "1":
   echo "<strong><font color=\"green\">Authorisation Granted!</font></strong>";
   break;
case "2":
   echo "<strong><font color=\"red\">Your card has expired and authorisation is denied</font></strong>";
   break;
case "3":
   echo "<strong><font color=\"red\">Your card has been cancelled and authorisation is denied</font></strong>";
   break;
default:
   echo "<strong><font color=\"red\">The Card ID does not exist</font></strong>";
}

//echo $_GET['here']; // Prints the name of the page content
//echo $class_obj_id; // Prints the id number of the selected row
?>
<?php } ?>
<div id="auth">
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">

<table id="auth" width="150" >
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><h2>Check Card Authorisation</h2></td>
   </tr>
<tr>
<td width="50" align="center">ID</td>
<td><input name="id" type="text" id="id" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="check" type="submit" id="check" value="Check">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: your code is vulnerable to xss attack. please avoid using `<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>` instead leave action as blank

Comment: Please can you give us a better idea of what you want the SQL query to achieve? For what purpose do you need to compare these numbers? If you just want to check if they match up etc

Comment: its just a prototype system . not actually going to be used

Comment: Okay i want to check the status of the drivers card. the original query selects the id from the card table , and fetches the field called state_id . it then does a switch to get the correct answer. I want to make it so that instead of the card id it uses the driver id to find the associated card and then return the status of that card.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM card c JOIN driver d ON c.referred_as=d.referred_as WHERE d.ID='$id'";
```

Comment: that didnt work , got this error : mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result

Comment: @Lazis002, try run the query directly on the database to see what the `real` problem is.

Comment: SQL query: Documentation

$sql = "SELECT * FROM card c JOIN driver d ON c.referred_as=driver.referred_as WHERE d.ID='$id'"

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$sql ="SELECT * FROM card c JOIN driver d ON c.referred_as=driver.referred_as WH' at line 1

Comment: what is returned if you just call: SELECT * FROM card c JOIN driver d ON c.referred_as=driver.referred_as

Comment: SQL query: Documentation

SELECT *
FROM card c
JOIN driver d ON c.referred_as = driver.referred_as
LIMIT 0 , 30

MySQL said: Documentation
#1054 - Unknown column 'driver.referred_as' in 'on clause'

Comment: Well it dosent come up with an error , but it does only show the final part of the switch if stament The Card ID does not exist

Comment: ...which would make sense, no?

Comment: no because the id from the driver table that i tested it linked to a card wich is valid and should display the first message

Comment: sorry I made a big mistake . turns out that thier is also a card_driver tbale which has the driver and card ids as fields . This table shows up as the associated_ parts of the other tables. That may be why it dosent work.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM driver INNER JOIN card ON driver.associated_card = card.associated_card WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Join the driver and card tables where the associated card id matches up, then you can just call your `$row['state_id']` from this

Comment: Sorry I will abandon this question to avoid further downvotes without a given reason. Good luck.